# Python/MySQL: Query executes but nothing happens?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm executing a simple query with Python but nothing seems to happen when it executes, just as if it skipped the execution.

Here's the code:

```
def somefunction(search_query):
    from django.db import connection, transaction

    search_query = search_query.strip()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    rows = cursor.execute("INSERT INTO searches (query) VALUES ('"+ search_query +"')")
```

There's nothing wrong with the query, i get no error message or nothing, it's just not working!

Any ideas?

Comment: Inserting `search_query` into an SQL query like this is a bad idea. `rows = cursor.execute("INSERT INTO searches (query) VALUES (%s)", [search_query])` would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you have to commit your changes:

```
cursor.execute('COMMIT')
```

Comment: I've never needed to use that before, but it worked! Thank you!